# Controls for Responsive Interface using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, controls

I've been writing web apps using MS MVC and KendoUI controls.

I'm moving to a project that will use a restful pattern implemented with MS WebApi 2.0 and a Responsive UI built with HTML5, Bootstrap and AngularJS.

I have experience writing the services, but I'm new to the client side, in particular AngularJS.  Can someone who has done this **recommend a control set that includes things like a date picker, autocomplete**...  ?  I've looked at JQueryUI.  **What do most Responsive UI developers use for controls?**

Thanks in Advance?

Comment: bootstrap is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Bootstrap and AngularJS, you can integrate [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) that makes Bootstrap functionality (e.g. date picker, typeahead, etc.) directly available in AngularJS code.

Comment: Thanks!  That's just what I was looking for!